# StreamBuilder shows only the results of the second MergeStream element

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream, rxdart

I'm trying to use a `SearchDelegate()` that can search among more than one stream. Now I'm trying to search among two. To merge both FireStore streams, I'm using `MergeStream()`. I'm not getting errors, but I only can see the results of the second stream. This is my code:

```
 Stream stream1 =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('stream1').snapshots();
    Stream stream2 =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('stream2').snapshots();


 Stream<QuerySnapshot> mergedStream =
        MergeStream([stream1, stream2]);

return StreamBuilder(
      stream: mergedStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData)
          return Center(
            child: Text('Loading...'),
          );

        final results = snapshot.data.docs.where(
          (DocumentSnapshot a) => a.data().toString().toLowerCase().contains(
                query.toLowerCase(),
              ),
        );

        return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
          child: ListView(................ etc,
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Rx.combineLatest` instead of `merge`